# Is Self Segue Better Approach for Code Reusability ? Issues with Self Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, segue

I have a UITableView within a UIViewController. Clicking on any cell results in a segue to another UITableView whose UI and elements are same as previous UITableView. In that case should i perform self segue (i.e. segue from UITableViewCell to same UIViewController ) or copy/paste the VC and make required array name changes in pasted VC. From Code Reusability point of view Self Segue seems to be a better option.

Facing following issue with Self Segue:-

If self segue is conditional i.e. e.g. if clicking on odd cell no results in segue to self while clicking on even no segue results in segue to UICollectionView , still it segues to self and then to required UICollectionView (in case of click on even no cell), not sure why? Anyone else facing similar issue?

**Note:** Please note all data is fetched asynchronously in both UITableView and UICollectionView and placed on main queue.